# Split string on capitalized/uppercase char

Tags: regex

I have following input:

```
MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock
SupportGie?\195?\159mannFlock
ABCSaskDgfskSblabla
```

And search for a regex which gives me following result:

```
Maintance Gie?\195?\159mann Flock
Support Gie?\195?\159mann Flock
ABC Sask Dgfsk Sblabla
```

For the first both strings I can use following regex `([A-Z]+)([^A-Z]*)`.
What do I have to change to make this regex work?

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Which language/regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/xAZvu)

Comment: Note that this does not split `AbC`, which may or may not be the desired behaviour.

Comment: @marcog: Right. If one wants a split in that case you can use `split/(?=[A-Z]+[^A-Z]?)/`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/(.)([A-Z][^A-Z])/$1 $2/g;
    say $_;
}

__DATA__
MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock
SupportGie?\195?\159mannFlock
ABCSaskDgfskSblabla
```

**output:**

```
Maintance Gie?\195?\159mann Flock
Support Gie?\195?\159mann Flock
ABC Sask Dgfsk Sblabla
```

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z](?=[^A-Z]))
```

This will find any uppercase letter followed by lowercase